Wait for command completion and capture output in interactive shell with Go crypto/ssh
After piping in a command to stdin after running session.RequestPty() and session.Shell(), there's seemingly no way to tell when that command is either done executing so I can try to parse stdout myself, or any way to directly get the output from the command. Additionally, I would like to be able to tell if a command is waiting for an interaction like pushing Y or entering a password.
Relevant code:
func connectSSH(username, host, identity, proxy string, resolve js.Value, reject js.Value) error {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    log.Println("Dialing WebSocket...")
    dialed, _, err := websocket.Dial(ctx, proxy, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to dial WebSocket: %v", err)
        return err
    }

    dialed.Ping(ctx)
    log.Println("WebSocket connection dialed")

    c := websocket.NetConn(context.Background(), dialed, websocket.MessageBinary)
    log.Println("NetConn created")

    signer, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey([]byte(identity))
    if err != nil {
        reject.Invoke(err.Error())
        return err
    }

    ncc, chans, reqs, err := ssh.NewClientConn(c, host, &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: username,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.PublicKeys(signer),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    })
    if err != nil {
        reject.Invoke(err.Error())
        return err
    }

    client := ssh.NewClient(ncc, chans, reqs)

    session, err := client.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        reject.Invoke(err.Error())
        return err
    }

    stdin, err := session.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        reject.Invoke(err.Error())
        return err
    }

    var stdoutBuf bytes.Buffer
    session.Stdout = &stdoutBuf

    stderr, err := session.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        reject.Invoke(err.Error())
        return err
    }

    modes := ssh.TerminalModes{
        ssh.ECHO:          0,     // disable echoing
        ssh.TTY_OP_ISPEED: 14400, // input speed = 14.4kbaud
        ssh.TTY_OP_OSPEED: 14400, // output speed = 14.4kbaud
    }
    // Request pseudo terminal
    if err := session.RequestPty("xterm", 40, 80, modes); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("request for pseudo terminal failed: ", err)
        reject.Invoke(err.Error())
        return err
    }

    // Execute the user's login shell
    if err := session.Shell(); err != nil {
        reject.Invoke(err.Error())
        return err
    }

    activeConnection = Connection{
        nc:      c,
        client:  client,
        wc:      dialed,
        session: session,
        stdin:   &stdin,
        stdout:  &stdoutBuf,
        stderr:  &stderr,
    }

    resolve.Invoke()
    return nil
}

func stdout(resolve, reject js.Value) {
    if activeConnection == (Connection{}) {
            reject.Invoke("no active connection")
            return
    }

    resolve.Invoke(stripansi.Strip(activeConnection.stdout.String()))
}

func execute(command string, resolve, reject js.Value) {
    if activeConnection == (Connection{}) {
        reject.Invoke("no active connection")
        return
    }

    n, err := (*activeConnection.stdin).Write([]byte(command + "\n"))

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error writing command to stdin: %v", err)
        reject.Invoke(err.Error())
        return
    }

    log.Printf("Wrote %d bytes to stdin", n)

    if closer, ok := (*activeConnection.stdin).(io.Closer); ok {
        err = closer.Close()
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error flushing stdin: %v", err)
            reject.Invoke(err.Error())
            return
        }
    }
    resolve.Invoke(n)
}


You are using a remote shell with a pty, this is an interactive shell so you need to parse the output just like you would as if you were typing in the commands yourself.

Yes I'm trying to use a remote shell so I can keep context across commands, how would I do that output parsing?

You must continue reading until you get the output you want, then act on it. In almost all cases you should instead run the commands non-interactively and wait for the process to exit

Is it possible to know when the command has finished exiting/waiting on user input before trying to parse stdout? Right now I'm waiting for an arbitrary time before checking but that is not a scalable solution

When you run an interactive command, the interface is the terminal. You need to read the terminal output, like you would do as a human with your eyes, parse that output, and determine the status of the command based on that output. Running interactive commands through a terminal is not a scalable solution to begin with. If you must do this, you can use something like expect (or various work-alike libraries)

Why not run ssh -e 'your;commands;here' non-interactively? This is pretty much what ansible does and as far as I can see it, you are trying to replicate some of it's functionality here.

That being said: Using expect(-a-like) functionality is almost always a huge pain in the lower backside when it comes to maintenance. And as for my previous comment, you might well be better off using the ssh client of the standard library. Have yet to find a better solution.


and as for my previous comment, you might well be better off using the ssh client of the standard library.
I am using that library, and the reason I need a shell is because I am trying to make my SSH client act as close to a standard shell as possible and I need to be able to use interactive commands like sudo/apt/etc


The more you describe, the more this sounds like a XY problem. sudo and apt, for example, can be run non-interactively. As far as I can see, you are trying to solve a problem which does not really exist.

I cannot predict what commands can be run as I am making a general library, you're right that those are not good examples however.

Uh... you are trying to write a general library for arbitrary interactive commands without providing a mechanism to react to their inputs?!?

What do you mean a mechanism to react to their inputs, sorry.


Uh... you are trying to write a general library for arbitrary interactive commands without providing a mechanism to react to their inputs?!?

Yes
